# Formula for standardized mean difference in Cobalt package for categorical variables

Tags: r, causality, propensity-scores, weighted-mean, weighted-data

I am having troubles in understanding the formula in `cobalt` package used for standardized mean difference calculation in BINARY variables

```
data("lalonde", package="cobalt")
library(WeightIt)
library(cobalt)
W.out <- weightit(treat ~ age + educ + race + married + nodegree + re74 + re75,
                  data = lalonde, estimand = "ATE", method = "ps")

table <- bal.tab(W.out, stats = c("m", "v"), thresholds = c(m = .10), disp=c("means", "sds") ,s.d.denom="pooled", un=TRUE,binary = "std"
)
```

For the unweighted population, I achieve the same results in binary variables by using this formula ([Austin, 2009](https://doi.org/10.1177/0272989X09341755)):

```
smd_bin <- function(x,y){
  z <- x*(1-x)
  t <- y*(1-y)
  k <- sum(z,t)
  l <- k/2
  
return((x-y)/sqrt(l))
  
}

smd_bin(x,y) #x is frequency in group 1, y frequency in group 2 e.g. race_black 0.8432 and 0.2028
smd(0.843243243243243,0.202797202797203)
[1] 1.670826
```

Which is the R formula for this:
[image]

However, when I have to calculate the SMD for the **WEIGHTED population**, I am having troubles since I don't obtain the same results.
To calculate the SMD in the WEIGHTED population I would apply the same formula as the one I wrote before but with weighted frequencies ([Austin,2011](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3144483/#s11title)), thus:

```
smd_bin(0.447822556953102,0.397896376833797)
[1] 0.1011917
```

But the `cobalt` package calculates it as: `0.130249813461064`

Two questions:

- What is the formula that cobalt package uses to calculate the weighted SMD categorical variables?
- If it doesn't calculate a weighted SMD, how can I calculate a weighted SMD for categorical variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mention in my [previous answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/618594/116195), `cobalt` always uses the unweighted variance in the denominator. That means you can't just supply the weighted proportions to your function and hope to get the right results; you need the unweighted proportions to compute the denominator of the SMD.

I have explained this choice [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/565705/116195) and [here](https://ngreifer.github.io/cobalt/articles/cobalt.html#variance-in-standardized-mean-differences-and-correlations) (so I won't do it again here). This is the best practice recommended in the literature and is described in the `bal.tab()` [documentation](https://ngreifer.github.io/cobalt/reference/bal.tab.html#with-binary-point-treatments).

So, we can write a new function that takes in the unweighted means and the weighted means.

```
smd_bin2 <- function(x, y, wx = x, wy = y){
  z <- x * (1 - x)
  t <- y * (1 - y)

  wz <- wx * (1 - wx)
  wt <- wy * (1 - wx)

  k <- z + t
  l <- k/2
  
  return((wx - wy)/sqrt(l))
}
```

For the unweighted SMD, we supply the unweighted means, as you have done:

```r
> smd_bin2(0.843243243243243, 0.202797202797203)
[1] 1.670826
```

For the weighted SMD, we additionally supply the weighted means:

```r
> smd_bin2(0.843243243243243,0.202797202797203,
           0.447822556953102,0.397896376833797)
[1] 0.1302498
```

Comment: I understand, however in the Austin's formula for categorical variables, there isn't the variance but only the weighted rate, that's why I keep not understanding the role of unweighted variance here (while for continous I understood). Is the denominator equal to variances?

Comment: The quantity $\hat p (1-\hat p)$ is the formula for the variance of a binary variable. It replaces the usual variance $s^2$ in the SMD formula. That's all Austin's formula is.

Comment: Thank you!! Now I understand!! You're great

Comment: Happy to help :)